VirtualBox V7.0 has Guest Control File Manager panels greyed out
VirtualBox V7.0 has a File Manager feature:

From the active guest terminal window > Machine > File Manager... displays:

It displays the host file system, but both the host and guest panels are greyed out. Why?

Where exactly did you screenshot the documentation from? Copying some text and googling it between double quotes brought me to these docs, but the design doesn't look the same even if it says the same thing, and I couldn't find the exact same text anywhere else. Would you mind to edit your post to include the link? Also, it would be nice if you quoted the docs instead of using an image. This way it will be esier to find this post in Google.


The Guest Control File Manager is a feature of the Guest Additions...


Note: To use the Guest Control File Manager, the guest must be running. For powered-off guests, it is disabled automatically.

You have to make sure the guest additions are installed and the guest turned on.
